# Python JSON Parsing'list indices must be integers'

Tags: json, python-2.7

I'm new to python (using python 2.7) and json. I'am trying to parse this json file (amended - saved in a file called distros.json)

```
[
    {
      "ip_prefix": "18.208.0.0/13",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "service": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
      "ip_prefix": "52.95.245.0/24",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "service": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
      "ip_prefix": "52.194.0.0/15",
      "region": "ap-northeast-1",
      "service": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
      "ip_prefix": "54.155.0.0/16",
      "region": "eu-west-1",
      "service": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
      "ip_prefix": "54.196.0.0/15",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "service": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
      "ip_prefix": "52.94.22.0/24",
      "region": "us-gov-east-1",
      "service": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
      "ip_prefix": "52.95.255.112/28",
      "region": "us-west-2",
      "service": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
      "ip_prefix": "13.210.0.0/15",
      "region": "ap-southeast-2",
      "service": "AMAZON"
    }
    ]
```

Every time there is an instance of the 'region' being 'us-east-1' I would like to print out the corresponding 'ip_prefix'.

I have hacked together the following:

```
import json

with open('distros.json', 'r') as f:
    distros_dict = json.load(f)

for distro in distros_dict:
    if (distros_dict['region'] == 'us-east-1'):
        print (distro_dict['ip_prefix'])
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 10, in <module>
    if (distros_dict['region'] == 'eu-west-1'):
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change these two lines:

```
if (distro['region'] == 'us-east-1'):
    print (distro['ip_prefix'])
```

You want to check the current item, the entire collection.